# Stringify error with parallel.js

Tags: javascript, multithreading

I am trying to parallelize a JavaScript project using parallel.js, but I am running into some kind of parsing problems.

The goal of the project is to have 9 ticket-sellers process customers in parallel. We have a working code right now, but the processing of the customers is still asynchronous, and we are trying to achieve the parallelization part using parallel.js.

My original code in JS before parallelizing is:

```
var ticketers = ["H", "M1", "M2", ...]; //There are 9 ticket-sellers

for(var i = 0; i < ticketers.length; i++) {
     ticketerBehavior(i);
}
```

Where ticketers are the 9 ticket-sellers, and ticketerBehavior() is the function that takes care of what happens when a ticket-seller receives a customer.

Using the parallel.js documentation and examples, this is what we tried out:

```
var ticketBehav = function(ticketers){
    for (var i = 0; i < ticketers.length; i++)
            ticketerBehavior(i);
};

var p = new Parallel(100);
p.spawn(ticketBehav(ticketers)).then(console.log(ticketBehav(ticketers)));
```

However, when we run the program, it gives us this error:

```
/home/user/node_modules/paralleljs/lib/parallel.js:106
        return preStr + 'process.on("message", function(e)      {process.send(JSON.stringify((' + cb.toString() + ')(JSON.parse(e).data)))})';
                                                                                               ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
at Parallel.getWorkerSource (/home/user/node_modules/paralleljs/lib/parallel.js:106:91)
```

I tried googling the error but it does not return any results so far. I was a little confused on how to troubleshoot this error, since our data is technically serializable as JSON since they are only strings. Would a version compatibility cause any issues with running parallel.js as well?

Could anyone please advise me on where to start troubleshooting? Any tips/advice would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: where cb variable is coming from? Have you log the value?

Comment: @jmmontero it's from the parallel.js module, and it returns undefined when I log it. I was thinking I am missing an argument somewhere, but I'm not sure exactly where since I'm following the example I found in the documentation.

Comment: could you please show me the whole example you are trying?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Pass your ticketers
2. For each ticket execute your function
3. Then return your data

   ```
   p.spawn(function (ticketers) {return ticketBehav(data)}).then(function(data){ console.log(data) });
   ```

Comment: it now gives me an error saying ticketBehav is not defined at eval.js (one of the node modules we use).